# Is the reading 缶【かん】の縁【えん】correct?

Tags: kanji, readings, collocations

Is the reading 缶【かん】の縁【えん】 correct?

缶【かん】の縁【えん】でけがをしないように気【き】を付【つ】けてください

*Be careful not to injure yourself on the rim of the can.*

https://www.bosai-nippon.com/article/4242?paged=2

I also found

縁【ふち】

and

縁【へり】

I found a number of examples here, but not an exact fit for the example sentence of "the rim of a can":

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/縁/#je-7004](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%B8%81/#je-7004)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, for the meaning of 'edge', it can never be えん.

I think 缶の縁{ふち} is more common, but 縁{へり} is acceptable too.

[This thesaurus entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/15469/meaning/m0u/) says

> ３「縁」は、平面状のもの、あるいは立体の外周部分をいう。
>
> ４「へり」は、平面状のものの外周部分をいう。「縁」とも書く。

As listed there, 目の縁{ふち} is more common than 目の縁{へり}. And 机の縁{へり} is more common than 机の縁{ふち}. My impression is 縁{ふち} is more about a point along the edge while 縁{へり} is the edge itself.  (Cf. 崖の縁{ふち}に立つ vs 畳の縁{へり}を歩いてはいけない.) But it is largely a matter of collocation.

Comment: What is the meaning with the えん reading?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel fate -- often in the sense of human relations being (supposedly) pre-destined. See [here](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=16720) for example.